# integration of continous random variable

Tags: integration

How can i calculate the variance of $y$ function

$Y = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}D_i + \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-l}D_j$

$i, j$ represents the time period
$n,l$ are constants
also it can be assumed that $D$ varies between $a$ and $b$ (both $a, b$ are constants).

I have also worked out for the discrete random variable and fine with the solution, however i would like to work for continuous random variable.
Secondly, the incorporate of time zones is purely out of my capabilities